# What does " I doubt we’ve heard the last word on quality models." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in the IEEE essay "A New Standard
for Quality Requirements".

In the article, the author, Jørgen Bøegh, says;

> Indeed, researchers have proposed several quality models with various sets of characteristics over the last 30 years. I
>   doubt we’ve heard the last word on quality models.

I don't actually understand what the sentence "I doubt we’ve heard the last word on quality models" means in this paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, @Fae. Now I understand what the sentence mean!

Answer (score 1):

"Indeed, researchers have proposed several quality models with various sets of characteristics over the last 30 years. *I doubt we’ve heard the last word on quality models."*

In this quote, *quality models* would be referring to a high grade or well designed product or system.

"I doubt we've heard the last word" is an expression, but it can also be understood very literally. The speaker does not think that the subject he is discussing has nothing left to say; he expects to hear more from it. Therefore, he doubts the information relayed to him was the last word from the subject.

In this case, the subject is the "quality models," and the previous sentence tells us the speaker is referring to what the researchers have been proposing for various models over the last 30 years.

So, altogether "I doubt we've heard the last word on quality models" could be understood as "We can expect more updates on quality models in the future."

Comment: I initially read "quality models" as meaning "quality products" but on looking at it again I started to think that it means something else. I now believe that it means "_models_ (probably mathematical models) _used to asses or investigate quality in some way_". I say this because the _reasearchers_ are _proposing_ the quality models. The sentence "I doubt we've heard the last  word on quality models" would then mean that the speaker expects quality modelling to be a continuing field of research activity and that the models will become more sophisticated as time goes on.